# Galaxybase server prompt:”Message hasn’t started.”

Tags: graph-databases

The Galaxybase server displays the prompt: "Message hasn't started."
what you tried and what you were expecting:
I attempted to interact with the Galaxybase server, but upon doing so, I encountered an issue where the server prompts that the message hasn't started. As for my expectation, I anticipated being able to successfully start and communicate with the server without any error messages.

I attempted to interact with the Galaxybase server, but upon doing so, I encountered an issue where the server prompts that the message hasn't started. As for my expectation, I anticipated being able to successfully start and communicate with the server without any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection was closed early because it did not consume the data correctly.

If the data returned by the server cannot be sent back to the client in one batch, the client is forced to close, which will cause the server to throw an exception.

This exception doesn't affect correctness, and it is necessary to verify that the client is consuming the data correctly.